My Python script can't access my Google Sheet
My Python script can't access my Google Sheet as I'm getting this error:
Exception has occurred: RefreshError
('invalid_grant: Invalid JWT Signature.', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Invalid JWT Signature.'})
I did the following in Google Cloud Console:
I enabled the Drive API
I enabled the Sheets API
I created credentials for both API's where I created service accounts where I set the role as editor
I created a private key in a JSON file and renamed it to client_secret.json and used it in the script below.
I opened the JSON file and used the value assigned to  "client_email" to share my Google Sheet to this address with editor access.
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open('Add stock').sheet1

clientlist = sheet.get_all_records()
print(clientlist)


What version of gspread are you using? It seems that the latest version is 6.1.0. In the case of version 6.1.0, when the service account is used, the following script can be used.
Before you use this script, please update your gspread to the latest version.
Sample script:
Please set the JSON file to serviceAccount.json of client = gspread.service_account("serviceAccount.json").
import gspread


client = gspread.service_account("serviceAccount.json")

sheet = client.open('Add stock').sheet1

clientlist = sheet.get_all_records()
print(clientlist)


In this case, it seems that the required scopes are automatically included with the library.
If client_secret.json of creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope) is for the service account, this script works. And, in this case, if Add stock cannot be accessed by the service account, an error like gspread.exceptions.SpreadsheetNotFound occurs. Please be careful about this. If you want to access the spreadsheet in your Google Drive, please share it with the email of the service account.

Note:

As additional information, the scope of https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds is used for Sheets API v3. In the current stage, if you want to use the scope of Sheets API v4, please use the scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets for Sheets API v4 instead of that of Sheets API v3. Ref

By the way, from client_secret.json of creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope), client_secret.json is for the service account? If you see the file content and you see client_secret in the file, I think that it is not for the service account. It is considered that it is for OAuth2. If it's so, please test the following script. If your client_secret.json is for OAuth2, please authorize the scopes when the script is run for the first time. By this, the retrieved refresh token and access token are saved to credential.json.
import gspread


client = gspread.oauth(
    credentials_filename="client_secret.json",
    authorized_user_filename="credential.json",
)

sheet = client.open('Add stock').sheet1

clientlist = sheet.get_all_records()
print(clientlist)



Reference:

Authentication of gspread


Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'serviceAccount.json'
File "C:\Users\Pieter\WhatsAppPython\spreadsheet.py", line 4, in 
client = gspread.service_account("serviceAccount.json")
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'serviceAccount.json'

@Pieter le Roux Thank you for replying. About Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'serviceAccount.json' File "C:\Users\Pieter\WhatsAppPython\spreadsheet.py", line 4, in <module> client = gspread.service_account("serviceAccount.json") ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'serviceAccount.json', I think that it indicates that in your situation, the filename of serviceAccount.json is not existing. Please set your file.

I changed the json file name from client_secret to serviceAccount and used the code provided in this answer, but still get this error

@Pieter le Roux When I tested my 1st script using the filename which does not exist, I confirmed that No such file or directory: '###' occurred. And, when I tested my 1st script using the valid filename which is the credential file of the service account, I confirmed that the script worked without errors. From this situation, I'm worried that about your error No such file or directory: 'serviceAccount.json', you might have used an invalid filename. I apologize for this situation. By the way, your client_secret.json is a valid credential file of the service account?

that was the file that was downloaded when I created the Private Key. I renamed it to client_secret.json. How can I be sure it's a valid credential file?

@Pieter le Roux Thank you for replying. About that was the file that was downloaded when I created the Private Key. I renamed it to client_secret.json. How can I be sure it's a valid credential file?, can you provide the key names which are not the values in client_secret.json? By the way, when I tested my 1st script using the valid filename which is the credential file of the service account, I confirmed that the script worked without errors. I apologize for this situation.

Suggestion: Generate a new Service key
I can replicate your error if the service account key is invalid or if the service account itself is disabled. Since the latter probably does not apply based on the detailed breakdown of the steps you followed, an invalid service account key is the most likely cause. I suggest deleting your existing private key and creating a new one, which will generate a new JSON file for authentication.
In addition, I suggest changing your scope to:
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

Using just https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds would throw a Request had insufficient authentication scope error.
